# What is the root/deeper meaning of ממילא?

Tags: translation, language

I am trying to understand what the word means and what its root is. How it comes to translate into "automatically" or "by itself", etc. What words is it related to? What is the relationship? What is the root word?

Comment: Why was this voted in the downward direction?